# Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I recently moved from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 on one of my projects and everything had been working fine. All of a sudden I started getting this error and I can't even figure out which method is missing.

The exception message I'm getting is :
`Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task1<Int32> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade, System.String, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Object[])'.`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I'm not getting any compile time errors and I've used this same method in the past. I've also tried putting break points before the method executes but it doesn't even hit the break point and an exception gets thrown.

I can provide any other information necessary.

Comment: I was getting a similar problem today (not related to Entity Framework, etc.) when I updated from 2.2 to 3.1. In my case, I was referencing Google.Cloud.Datastore in one class library, and Google.Cloud.PubSub in another class library. Their versions conflicted, and the one that took precedence didn't have a method that the other one expected. Perhaps you have a conflict like that somewhere?

Comment: @John I was trying to find any possible conflicts but wasn't able to trace any down. I know our situations aren't the same but the only thing I saw was `'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Code\ksg\src\KSG.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll'`

Not sure if that helps at all. I don't know if that netcoreapp2.1 is related to a .net standard version or not

Comment: I'd check if any of your NuGet packages have newer versions, especially those related to System.Data.SqlClient. I was fortunate in that I only had a single Google package in another class library that could possibly be causing my issue. Yours looks more like a problem with one of the Microsoft packages.

Comment: I did update all of my NuGet packages. I also tried different version of them. I didn't want to roll back to 2.2 if I didn't have to but that might be my next step. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I was using the incorrect NuGet package in my project after upgrading to .net core 3.1.

I was using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design` version 1.1.6 which was not the correct package. I should have been using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` version 3.1.0 or higher.

By using the first NuGet package it was giving me access to the `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` at compile time and not throwing any errors but at runtime the method was not found. I should have instead been using `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` which was changed when moving to .net core 3 or greater.

Hopefully this helps someone else also.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped me diagnose a similar problem with MongoDB driver version mismatch. One of the projects in my solution was referencing MongoDB driver NuGet package directly, but another project referenced some other NuGet package that happened to depend on a different version of the same MongoDB driver package.  These projects compiled separately without any problems, but in the final build output, the latter driver version prevailed, so at runtime my code was trying to call into an unexpected version, hence `System.MissingMethodException` was raised.